# What was the vampire movie where the protagonist gets cow's blood?

Tags: story-identification, movie, vampire, horror

The guy got a big wound in his stomach and his friend tells him "shit shit" comes from
your stomach, but after that they repaired it and made the guy drink cow's blood
and he returned to normal.

I cannot remember the movie's title but I never forgot that scene.  What was the name of that movie?

Answer (score 6):

I believe the movie your talking about is called [*Afflicted*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Afflicted_%28film%29).  Two friends are filming a web series in Europe and one becomes a vampire.

From [a review](http://www.cherubcow.com/post/87380553778/afflicted-20132014-movie-review):

> Maybe 45 minutes into the movie, they know that Lee has become a vampire, and they know he needs to feed. They start procedurally but then fall apart, first seeing if he can eat store-bought cow’s blood, then seeing if he can drink a live animal’s blood (because maybe he needs fresh blood).

Answer (score -1):

It might be Little Vampire. Its a kids movie but there was a character that drank cow blood.

Answer (score -1):

i guess this is from the 80's and they were in a barn, Its like  LOST BOYS

Comment: When you say _"it's like Lost Boys"_, do you mean you think it **is** _The Lost Boys_, or that it's another film **similar** to _The Lost Boys_...? Also, what makes you think it's from the '80s?

Answer (score -5):

I don't know for sure, but if it was an older movie it might be Once Bitten with a young Jim Carrey.

Comment: That doesn't sound at all like *Once Bitten*.

Comment: Nope - definitely not Once Bitten.

Comment: If you don't know, don't answer...